# Remove chartjs pie chart highlight on hover

Tags: chart.js, pie-chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvxl2.png)

Above when I hover over the chart it highlights the section Im hovering over with a grey border. What can I do to remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hoverBorderWidth` property to remove the border on hover like this:

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      datasets: [
        data: [//data here],
        hoverBorderWidth: 0
      ]
    },
    options: options
});
```